# How can I remove image from Fabric.js canvas using button

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm very new to canvas and Fabric.js. I follow some tutorial and now can add image to canvas. but have no idea how to remove it. by clicking a button

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
   <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
   <input type="button" id="imageRemove" name="imageRemove" />
   <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="width:400px;height:400px" ></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(240,240,240)'
});

var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

function handleImage(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
            scaleX: 1,
            scaleY: 1
        })
        canvas.add(imgInstance);
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}

var imageRemove = document.getElementById('imageRemove');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleRemove, false);

function handleRemove(e) {
   canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject());
}
```

Edit:

Here is [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndtwcbt9/)

Comment: could you make quick fiddle?

Comment: Done! Fiddle above. @Amy

Comment: Click event on remove button is not working

Comment: you are giving to imageLoader 2 different functions on change. the second function should be for imageRemove on click

Comment: @Expl0de Please refer my posted answer

Comment: Remove is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `clear()` for clearing the canvas object and use `renderAll()` for redraw the given canvas.

Try This Code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/atate143/LmL9jwLq/)**

HTML:

```
    <div id="container">
    <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
    Remove:<input type="button" value="remove" id="imageRemove" name="imageRemove" onClick="handleRemove()"/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="width:400px;height:400px" ></canvas>
```

JS Code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(240,240,240)'
});

var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

function handleImage(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
            scaleX: 1,
            scaleY: 1
        })
        canvas.add(imgInstance);
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}

//var imageRemove = document.getElementById('imageRemove');
//imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleRemove, true);

function handleRemove() {
canvas.clear().renderAll(); // Here is your clear canvas function
}
```

Comment: This will clear the whole canvas not just the image, right? What if there is image and text, but we want just to remove the text not the image? Also the clearing of text not by selecting the text but by checkbox action. If checkbox is clicked, show text otherwise remove text.